# Scraping some data using PHP

Tags: php

I like to have update of some selected users score from https://location.services.mozilla.com/leaders For that i want to scrape their data using the id as you see for the first user `<a id="g@v" href="#g@v">g@v</a>`
I want to have his data using the id on that anchor. I have wrote the attached code but, couldn't succeed. Best if i could create an array like $names=array("g@v","elly","elkos"," grack"); and get the scores of all of them, so if i increase the number of names, i can have everyone's score. I was trying for a single user though:

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('https://location.services.mozilla.com/leaders');
    $pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    if(!empty($html)){
        $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);
        $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//a[@id="g@v"]');
        if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
            foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
                $name = $row->nodeValue;
                $scores = $pokemon_xpath->query('//.td.tr/td[@class="text-right"]', $row);
                foreach($scores as $score){
                    $lead = $score->nodeValue;
                }
                echo $name . ": ". $lead;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to look for `tr`s and then you know that the first td is rank, second td is name, third td is points. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your scraping code to display all users and their score:

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('https://location.services.mozilla.com/leaders');
    $pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    if(!empty($html)){
        $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);
        $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//tr');
        if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
            // Get each tr
            foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
                // Get each td in the tr group
                $tds = $row->childNodes;
                foreach($tds as $td){
                    // Filter out empty nodes
                    if(trim($td->nodeValue, " \n\r\t\0\xC2\xA0") !== "") {
                        $name = $td->nodeValue;
                        echo $name . " ";
                    }
                }
                echo "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This will print out:

```
Rank User Points 
1. g@v 18444343 
2. elly 4458330 
3. elkos 4452607 
4. grack 2769789 
5. sonickydon 2707133 
6. SDBoyd 2636721 
...
```

If you want to search for a single user, then just replace the query line with this:

```
$pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//tr[td/a[@id="g@v"]]');
```

which will print:

```
1. g@v 18444343
```

Hope that helps.